# ~/.bashrc not working behind corporate proxy

Tags: git-bash

here is the script I wrote inside ~/.bashrc

```
(curl https://google.com -m 2 && clear) || (export HTTPS_PROXY='http://username:password@http-mycompany.com:8080' && echo "done")
```

this is basically to set the proxy whenever I use the git bash when I am inside VPN and not otherwise :)

[The output whenever I open the git bash when in vpn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWOr4.png)

also when I do "echo $HTTPS_PROXY" the output doesn't show the proxy URL

am I missing something here, It worked earlier actually :p

(if it helps OS: Windows 10, git version - 2.15)

Comment: Please include the output directly in this question, not in an image (especially inked off site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> also when I do "echo $HTTPS_PROXY" the output doesn't show the proxy URL

That is because HTTPs_PROXY is set within the sub-shell inside the `(  )` expression. And it is lost after that.

It is better to avoid those `()`, [as in here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125002/7490):

```
curl https://google.com -m 2
if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then
  export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@http-mycompany.com:8080
  export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@http-mycompany.com:8080
  export NO_PROXY=mycompany.com,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,.local
  echo "done"
fi
```

Note: it is best to define also `HTTP_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY`.